# how to get inner html from current aspx page in code behind

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

How would I be able to get the innerHtml of the current aspx page in codebehind? I want to use the innerHTML and pass to a pdf converter function when the user clicks the pdf button, but i need the current page html as string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do a postback and use javascript to provide the current innerHTML

```
__doPostBack(**event target**, document.documentElement.innerHTML);
```

Comment: It would be `document.documentElement.innerHTML`, not `document.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `Render` method of the page.

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     HtmlTextWriter tw = new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(sb));
     base.Render(tw);
     string innerHtml = sb.ToString();
}
```

innerHtml will contain whole rendered html code of page. A little simplified version.

Comment: @ilyabreev This method does work, however I want to catch the inner html before the Render. So I used the __doPostBack method. Thanks.

Comment: FYI if you do that, nothing will render.

Comment: Sure! This is just about how to capture whole page render to a string.